# Magento 1.9 : Product importing not working

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products, import-products

I have tried both Import/Export and the Dataflow method for importing the products in Magento 1.9. 
In both cases, it's giving a success message. But the product not importing to the backend.
Can you please what is exactly happening here? I am adding the screenshots.

Thanks in advance.
[image: System > Import / Export > Import]
[image: Import Success Message]

Comment: Did you indexing after import all products..?

Comment: yes, done reindexing. But no difference.

Comment: Search your SKU in your Database, store in database or not..?

Comment: simple way to do this task is first export the existing product and ammend the csv for your new products and use that csv to export

Comment: @Mujahidh Yes, I am importing the same CSV file.

Comment: @sangeeta Nop, I have done this. Don't know whats exactly happening